# How to filter multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have data:

```
structure(list(A = structure(c(7L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("i", "o", "q", "r", "s", "u", "w", "x", "y"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1), EDU = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "D", 
"E", "F"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

My output is:

```
structure(list(A = structure(c(4L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("q", 
"r", "s", "w", "x", "y"), class = "factor"), Value = c(2, 2, 
 2, 3, 2, 3), EDU = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to filter EDU column having `value >= 2` and should be present in all of `column A`.

Like for examples in row element "A" in column EDU has all the values above 2 in  2nd column  . This will be my all the element of 1st column above 2 so first column all values are above 2 for EDU "A"

I tried multple filter option of dplyr but no success.

Comment: What do you mean "and should be present in all of column A"?  It seems like `df %>% filter(Value >= 2)` achieves your output - are there additional edge cases that are unaccounted for?

Comment: Hi @andrew_reece as you see in column 1 more then 2 is available for all the element in column 1 that belongs to element  "A" of EDU column .

Comment: the person who flagged this question for closing has deleted his wrong illogical code.

Comment: @KMISH, the output data.frame is your desired result? If so, why isn't the solution of andrew_reece ok?

Comment: Make more clear what you want. Is to subset Value and EDU? `filter(Value >= 2 & EDU == 'A')`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of code, it works for me !

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("w","r","x","y","q","s","u","i","o"),
             Value = c("2","2","2","3","2","3","1","1","1"),
             EDU = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","D","E","F"))


# The two first columns have been transformed in numeric
n <- ncol(df) - 1
for(i in 1:n){
 df[,i] <- as.numeric(df[,i])
}

# Filter
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df1 <- df %>%
 filter(Value >= 2 & EDU == "A")
```